# Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'unicode'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2008, unicode

Hi i am creating a application in vb.net using 3 tier architecture.

My DB Connection is:

```
Implements IDisposable
    Public Shared ReadOnly mcpConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con1").ConnectionString
    Private _McpConnection As OracleConnection
```

Business Layer is:

```
Public Class blayer
    Inherits DBConnection
    Public Sub ses_test_insert(ByVal p_userid As Integer, ByVal p_username As String, ByVal p_createdby As String, ByVal p_date As String)
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(mcpConnectionString, "insertDBUSER", p_userid, p_username, p_createdby, p_date)
    End Sub
```

In Web Config:

```
<add name="con1" connectionString="Data Source=xe;User ID=system;Password=sesu;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

I am using Oracle as a back end tool. I created Procedure in oracle insertDBUSER....

I am not able to insert data into table. When i am click insert button it shows

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'unicode'.

Source Error: 


Line 12:     Inherits DBConnection
Line 13:     Public Sub ses_test_insert(ByVal p_userid As Integer, ByVal p_username As String, ByVal p_createdby As String, ByVal p_date As String)
Line 14:         SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(mcpConnectionString, "insertDBUSER", p_userid, p_username, p_createdby, p_date)
Line 15:     End Sub
Line 16: End Class
```

Whats the problem.?

After removing unicode it shows:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I ran into the same problem today. **Oracle does support "Unicode=True"**. You get this error and the following error if you try to connect to Oracle with a SQL server connection System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.  Use System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection (or some other ADO.Net Oracle provider) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string it says:

```
Unicode=True
```

Obviously Oracle does not support it, you should remove it.

Comment: After removed Unicode it shows  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)